# How to prevent Google Analytics from adding a second slash between domain and page specific URL when viewing a page?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a blog `http://foo.tumblr.com`. I sometimes go to  `Site Content - All Pages` on Google Analytics and then navigate to page listing and then click the icon to take me to that page on my blog. However, instead of opening `http://foo.tumblr.com/post/1234/blah.html` Google Analytics is opening `http://foo.tumblr.com//post/1234/blah.html` (i.e., it is adding a second slash between the domain the page specific component of the URL).
How can I stop Google Analytics from doing this?

Comment: I also have the same case. I checked the admin property settings but no slash on my URL. However, there is in the property settings. will check in the next days for the result. I agree with Jeromy

Answer (score 1):

This site has multiple solutions for the double slash http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/double-slashes-in-analytics-urls/

Answer (score 1):

This is now in Admin -> "View Settings" (right hand column) under "default page" with the new Analytics layout...

Answer (score 0):

In your Google Analytics, check under the Admin page, the Property settings for the site. In the default URL, perhaps you are leaving behind one more slash, take that out and GA will start showing the correct URLs from the day you make this change.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but my default URL is like `http://foo.tumblr.com`. i.e., it is not `http://foo.tumblr.com/`.

Comment: It seems that the URL was fine on the  property settings page, but there was an extra slash on the profile settings page.

Answer (score 0):

You have a slash on the end of your website URI **configuration profile.**

Answer (score 0):

Remove the trailing slashes from your site name in Google Analytics on your admin page.

Answer (score 0):

Several people mention removing the trailing slash in the website URL in Google Analytics.
I had checked my website "property settings" and there was no trailing slash in the website URL.

However, there is a separate "profile settings" page which did have a trailing slash. When I removed the slash from this page, the problem was fixed.